# How can I save a dying wiki, as its user?

Tags: user-retention, site-growth, wiki

I'm a semi-regular user of a game-related wiki, and I've noticed an extreme drop of activity after a sequel to the game came out. I hoped it was temporary occurrence, and we'd start to get users back on our wiki, but so far it's only getting more and more inactive.

Right now the wiki is in extremely bad shape, users can't keep up with vandalism.

I've tried contacting the wiki administrator, but I wasn't able to reach them, I also don't know any active moderators on the site.

**What should I do, as a user, to save this wiki?**

Comment: You could always advertise on social media etc. and simply state that it isn't an official page.

Answer (score 9):

If the game is effectively dead now that the sequel is out then it might be the time to cut your losses and move on.

However, if the information is valuable - true if people are going to continue playing the original game - then perhaps you need to look at archiving the information to another read-only site. This would preserve the information, but would make it much harder to update should it become necessary.

Ideally you want to lock the current wiki - you have to consider incoming links and bookmarks - but locking of wiki's seems to be frowned upon and you would need to be an admin to do it anyway.

Comment: I don't have access to any moderation/administration tools and was unable to reach the owner. I'm a normal user on the wiki.

Comment: @Mateon1 - I know, which is why I suggested what I did. Anything else you could do (that I could find) relies on you being an admin.

Comment: And yes, the game is still played quite a bit and the information is valuable, the wiki is not very known, though.

Comment: You can still save a mirror of the wiki using a web-crawling downloader like wget or Teleport. It will be read-only by nature if you publish it...

Comment: Where are users of the new sequel getting their information?  Is there a new wiki or other community asset addressing this? If there is no way to save this old Wiki because its owner is absent, then why not create your own wiki, starting with cloning relevant information from the old one, and linking back to it as an archive?

Comment: @Mateon1, Assuming the rights are permissible, I suggest you create a new Wiki based on the contents of the old Wiki. For this new Wiki you can set in "edit guards" since you are the mod.